# Java: compareTo for generic T objects

Tags: java, generics, compareto

I have the following code, how can I use the compareTo method with primitive types:

```
public class mySortertedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends myLinkedList<T> {
    
    class Node {
    Node next = null;
    T data;
    Node (T x) {
        data = x;
    }
}


public int compareTo (T Obj) {
        return this.compareTo(Obj);
}
```

Basically what I have is a sorted linked list which adds values to the list based on the compareTo method. How can I make sure that the compareTo works for primitive types, at least Integers? Any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT: To clarify, here is more code:
The main programme :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    newList.addTo(4);
    newList.addTo(1337);
    newList.addTo(30);
    newList.addTo(15);
}
```

I also have other methods like get(int index), remove() i.e. removes the last element in the list. Here is the addTo method from mySortertList<T extends Comparable> class, there is a declaration of variable start of type Node, it is really just a pointer as a starting point to go through the whole linked list one by one:

```
private Node start = null;

public void addTo(T x) {
        Node newNode = new Node(x);
        Node pointer = start;
        if (start == null) {
            start = newNode;
        } else if (size()==1){
            if (newNode.data.compareTo(start.data)<0) {
                newNode.next= start;
                start = newNode;
            } else {
                start.next= newNode;
            }
        } else {
    

            boolean valuePlaced= false;
            Node pointer2= start.next;
    
            while (pointer2 !=null) {
                if (newNode.data.compareTo(pointer.data)<0) {
                    newNode.next= start.next;
                    start.next = newNode;
                    valuePlaced = true;
                } else if (newNode.data.compareTo(pointer2.data)<0) {
                    pointer = newNode;
                    new.next= pointer2;
                    valuePlaced = true;
                }
                pointer = pointer.next;
                pointer2 = pointer2.next;
            }
            
            if (valuePlaced == false) {
                pointer.next= newNode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) where _exactly_ is your primitive here 2) do not compare strings with `==` 3) this question makes little sense

Comment: Eugene, when I make a list in the main Program, I make it like mySortedList<Integer>, and I pass in int values to the compareTo method, like this.data.compareTo(x.data), but since the compareTo only works on classes, not primitives, it won't work.

Comment: Also, that if statement where I use == to compare String is because I know exactly what (Object)Obj.getClass().getName() is will be if Obj is an instanceof the primitive type int. I use this because I cannot called instanceof int on a generic object.

Comment: Could you provide us a few lines of code where you (1) declare the list of integers, (2) implements the method compareTo ? Here it seems it is in Node class or mySortertedList class. It is not clear enough.

Comment: g.momo just added the main programme and the addTo method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether I got you well, but this is what I can suggest you :

- assuming `compareTo()` is in class Node... (**)
- I tested with `LinkedList<T>` instead of your `myLinkedList<T>`

The following works correctly at my ends.

```java
// we are in file Test.java
public class Test { 
   public static void main(String... args) {
        mySortertedList<Integer> newList = new mySortertedList<>();
        newList.addTo(4);
        newList.addTo(1337);
        System.out.println("newList "+ newList.toString()); // newList , 4, 1337
        newList.addTo(30);
        System.out.println("newList "+ newList.toString()); // newList , 4, 30, 1337
        newList.addTo(15);
        System.out.println("newList "+ newList.toString()); // newList , 4, 15, 30, 1337
    }
}
class mySortertedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends LinkedList<T> { // rather than your myLinkedList<T>

    private Node start = null;

    class Node {
        Node next = null;
        T data;
        Node(T x) {
            data = x;
        }

        public int compareTo(T Obj) { // (**)
            if ((Object) Obj.getClass().getName() == "java.lang.Integer") {
                return Integer.compare((Integer) this.data, (Integer) Obj);
            } else {
                return this.compareTo(Obj);
            }
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        Node pointer2= start;

        while (pointer2 !=null) {
            s += ", "+ pointer2.data.toString();
            pointer2 = pointer2.next;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void addTo(T x) {
        Node newNode = new Node(x);
        Node pointer = start;
        if (start == null) {
            start = newNode;
        } else if (start.next == null) { // (size()==1){ 
            if (newNode.data.compareTo(start.data)<0) {
                newNode.next= start;
                start = newNode;
            } else {
                start.next= newNode;
            }
        } else {
            boolean valuePlaced= false;
            if (newNode.data.compareTo(start.data)<0) {
                newNode.next= start;
                start = newNode;
            }
            else {
                while (valuePlaced == false && pointer.next != null) {
                    if (newNode.data.compareTo(pointer.next.data) < 0) {
                        newNode.next = pointer.next;
                        pointer.next = newNode;
                        valuePlaced = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    pointer = pointer.next;
                }

                if (valuePlaced == false) {
                    pointer.next = newNode;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To test, just create a Test.java and copy paste this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `compareTo` for all cases.

`Integer` is a class, *not* a primitive.  `int` is a primitive, but it can't appear in generics.  You don't need to do anything special whatsoever, and can just use `compareTo`, which works fine on `Integer`.

It is *impossible* for `obj` to be a primitive (in current versions of Java).  `obj` will always be an object.

Comment: Louis Wasserman, I have list composed of int types. Now to add the int values, I want to use compareTo everytime a new int value is added to the list i.e. the larger int values go to the back of the list. Problem is I cannot cast int into a Integer (gives error: The constructor Integer(T) is not defined), neither can I pass in int values into the compareTo function because I get error int cannot be deferenced. I know Obj is always object, but I also want to pass in Integer values, for that I need that the int value I pass in is either converted to Integer class.